# Why aren't my media query break points triggering for this image?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, breakpoints

I have a media query set to display a different image for screens less than 480px, but the image isn't changing at the break point. [Here is a jsfiddle for the whole email.](https://jsfiddle.net/jarrodwhitley/coed9xhe/) The media query is below.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/ CLIENT-SPECIFIC MOBILE STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
                body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;} /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes */
                body{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;} /* Prevent iOS Mail from adding padding to the body */

                *[class].social-cell {
                    width: 100% !important;
                }
                *[class].social-spacer {
                    height: 10px !important;
                }
                .hero-image .top-image {
                    background-image: url('http://i1045.photobucket.com/albums/b451/stonerootmedia/header-image%20-480px_zpsyffs7ced.png') !important}
            }
```

Comment: Why not put the media query in the Fiddle?

Comment: I put the whole HTML code in Fiddle in case there were conflicts within my code. I just put the snippet here to make sure that I'm not doing something blatantly wrong. That's why I included both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `.hero-image .top-image` to `.hero-image.top-image`. With space between class names you are looking for an element with class `.top-image`, but whos parent element has class `.hero-image`.

It will technically work but still won't be what you would expect, because the original image is set in `img` `src` attribute and that will hide whatever background-image you have.

Comment: So how do I fix that then? Do I need to not have an img src and have the background-image set in CSS?

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help.